# getting n consecutive bits set/unset in a array

Tags: c

I want to find the position from where `n` consecutive bits are set or unset in a array.

example array:

```
a[0] = 0x0fffffff  
a[1] = 0x000000f0  
a[2] = 0xffffff00
```

If I want to the find first 8 unset bits it must return 28 (28th bit position in array)

If I want to find first 32 unset bits it must return 40 (40th bit position in array)

I'm trying to expand upon code that I found [here](https://tekpool.wordpress.com/category/bit-count/) so that it will work with an arbitrarily large array:

```
int BitCount(unsigned int u)
 {
         unsigned int uCount;

         uCount = u
                  - ((u >> 1) & 033333333333)
                  - ((u >> 2) & 011111111111);
         return
           ((uCount + (uCount >> 3))
            & 030707070707) % 63;
 }
```

Comment: Please show your code and comment on where you think it is "not a good way" so people can give you useful answers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i was able to putdown some basic code for 32-bit integer, not able to extend to a array of variable size. hence came to experts

Comment: Show us what you have for the 32-bit integer, maybe we can help expand your current solution

Comment: here is what i have for 32-bit

// From: http://tekpool.wordpress.com/category/bit-count/
'
int BitCount(unsigned int u)

{

unsigned int uCount;


uCount = u
- ((u >> 1) & 033333333333)
- ((u >> 2) & 011111111111);
return
((uCount + (uCount >> 3))
& 030707070707) % 63;
}

int First0Bit(int i)
{
i=~i;
return BitCount((i&(-i))-1);
}
'

I think this is very fast for int-sized datatypes(32 bit).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

Simply loops through the array and checks 1 bit at a time to see whether its set or not.

```
int UnsetBits(unsigned int a[], int sizeOfArray, int requiredBits)
{
    //number of found bits in a row
    int found = 0;

    //current index in array
    int index = 0;

    //current bit
    int bit = 0;

    while(index < sizeOfArray)
    {
        //isolate the current bit
        int data = ((a[index] << (31 - bit)) >> 31);

        //bit is unset
        if(data == 0)
        {
            found++;

            //found required amount, return start position
            if(found == requiredBits)
            {
                return bit + 1 + (index * 32) - requiredBits;
            }
        }
        //bit is set, reset found count
        else
        {
            found = 0;
        }

        //increment which bit we are checking
        bit++;

        //increment which array index we are checking
        if(bit >= 32)
        {
            bit = 0;
            index++;
        }
    }

    //not found
    return -1;
}
```